# Markdown wikiengine

Tags: .net, markdown, wiki-engine

Do anyone know of a wiki engine that uses markdown?

I'm not going to use ASP.Net, but do post ASP.Net based solutions anyway if you know any.

### Update

Please note the **.Net** tag. I'm only interested in Markdown engines that have been built using .Net.

Comment: if you decide to code your own engine in asp.net MVC, Spark View Engine has a Markdown support, it integrates seamlessly in the views via a <Markdown> tag. PS: If you're looking for a web solution in .NET, I'm afraid you're going to use ASP.NET...

Comment: ok. asp.net is OK as long as it's open source so that I can adapt the engine to my web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

- Markdown Sharp,( initially called Markdown.NET, a C# implementation of the Markdown text processor) and a
- wiki .Net library such as SushiWiki

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sushiwiki/

Answer (score 7):

[MarkDoc](http://markdoc.org/) is a great minimal wiki engine which uses Markdown.

**edit:** I did't undestrand the first version of your question because the *.net* clarification has been inserted later. Anyway I leave my answer for general information which someone could find useful.

Comment: Can it be integrated in a .Net application? I think not, looks like a stand-alone system.

Comment: @jgauffin the first version of your question was not complete. `I'm not going to use ASP.Net.`. I think that the .net tag was not enough to give @Antonio a downvote.

Comment: imho it was. Tags are used to specify technologies that you are asking for. I'm not going to use ASP.Net, but that doesn't mean that I'm looking for a markdown engine in any language. Hence the .net tag. Antonio would have received +1 if I wanted to find any markdown engine.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but what I mean is even simpler: I don't think that "misunderstanding a question" is worth a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

DokuWiki with plugin dokuwiki.org/plugin:markdownextra
Oddmuse with extension oddmuse.org/cgi-bin/oddmuse/Markdown_Extension
ikiwiki ikiwiki.info/features/
PmWiki with extension pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/MarkdownMarkupExtension

Comment: can all of those be integrated in a .Net application? I think not. They are complete wikis in php.

Answer (score 0):

http://wikicontrol.codeplex.com

any other implementations?

Comment: I think that you should answer your own question only when that *is* the answer (in that case you should also mark it as the accepted answer). Otherwise, you should edit the question. Anyway, I'm not a mod, so if I'm wrong correct me.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. I can provide answers and I do not have to mark them as an answer. I want to award the question to anyone who finds an alternative. Edits are to improve the question not to answer it.